# Has anyone used SecureBlackBox?

Tags: c#, security, sockets

Has anyone used SecureBlackBox? It is a library that can be used with sockets to encrypt the data sent over the socket.

I have a project that uses it, and to send a packet of data which is around about 976Kb using the SecureBlackBox library it takes 12 seconds.

If I strip out the library and just use normal sockets it takes from between 0.72 and 1.72 seconds.

Anybody else seen anything similar? I am not sure I can understand why some encryption and decryption would slow it down so must. It is a show stopper, and the library will have to go if it is indeed causing that much slowdown.

As mentioned below I can now see that two different types of sockets in the SecureBlackBox library are behaving differently. On the client side if a TElSimpleSSLClient is used it is fast, but if a ElClientSSLSocket is used it is slow.

In both cases a ElServerSSLSocket is used on the server.

The license keys used in both cases are exactly the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems secure black box is a bit secretive about their sockets. Perhaps there are some bugs? Asking me to go to support, and not being straight up with me eh!

Answer (score 2):

Did you read the nag screen information? Evaluation key has delays that slow down operations. You can [request the trial key](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/keyreq/) which removes speed limitations.

Comment: Thanks, but the bizarre thing is that I am actually talking about a version of this software that is in production, i.e. it has a valid license. I might post some details later, but it seems like a certain type of socket in the SecureBlackBox that is slow, and one of the other types is quicker.

Comment: I guess the trial license key was kept in the code somehow. I suggest that you come to EldoS support directly.

Comment: Yep OK, but I can tell you definately that no trial keys are involved here.

Comment: In one case it is using a TElSimpleSSLClient (which is the case where it is fast). The other case is using a ElClientSSLSocket (which is the case where it is slow). The license keys in both cases are the same I just checked.

Comment: In both cases a ElServerSSLSocket is used on the server.